# Optimising php code for list of items

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I'm using joomla! to output some extra fields into an article. The fields are a list of images (max of 10) which are displayed using backslider jquery plugin.

Here is the code i've used which works:

```
<div id="bs0" class="backslider">
    <ul class="bs-slides">
        <?php 
            $img1 = $this->item->extrafields['image_1'];
            $img2 = $this->item->extrafields['image_2'];
            $img3 = $this->item->extrafields['image_3'];
            $img4 = $this->item->extrafields['image_4'];
            $img5 = $this->item->extrafields['image_5'];
            $img6 = $this->item->extrafields['image_6'];
            $img7 = $this->item->extrafields['image_7'];
            $img8 = $this->item->extrafields['image_8'];
            $img9 = $this->item->extrafields['image_9'];
            $img10 = $this->item->extrafields['image_10'];
        ?>
        <?php if($img1) { ?>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $img1; ?>"></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($img2) { ?>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $img2; ?>"></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($img3) { ?>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $img3; ?>"></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($img4) { ?>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $img4; ?>"></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($img5) { ?>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $img5; ?>"></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($img6) { ?>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $img6; ?>"></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($img7) { ?>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $img7; ?>"></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($img8) { ?>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $img8; ?>"></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($img9) { ?>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $img9; ?>"></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($img10) { ?>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $img10; ?>"></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm not a php expert but is there a better way of optimising this code, I'm thinking maybe putting the $img variables into an array and using a foreach loop to output each list item?

A little help wouldn't go a miss :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below will avoid evaluating strings, cache's everything you can, to keep your application running smoothly, and keeps your code nice and tidy.

```
<div id="bs0" class="backslider">
    <ul class="bs-slides">
        <?php
        // Generate length of our image array / store known length of array
        $images = 10;

        // Loop through images
        for( $i = 1; $i <= $images; $i++ ) {
            // Store it for optimization sake.
            $field = $this->item->extrafields['image_' . $i];

            // Check it's not empty
            if( !empty( $field ) ) {

                // If not, print to browser
                printf(
                    '<li><img src="%s" alt=""></li>',
                    htmlspecialchars($field)
                );
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate over them and use the index to reference the array indices:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; ++$i) {
    if (!empty($this->item->extrafields["image_$i"])) {
         echo '<li><img src="', htmlspecialchars($this->item->extrafields["image_$i"]), '"></li>';
    }
}
```

Assuming there are up to 10 items to investigate.

Comment: Trouble with this is it displays a blonk slide if only 9 are uploaded? Is there a way of testing to display a list item only if it has an image?

Comment: @Rob Good to know; btw, `empty` is technically not a function but a language construct :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will do same thing.

```
<div id="bs0" class="backslider">
    <ul class="bs-slides">
        <?php 
            for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
            {
                $img = $this->item->extrafields['image_'.$i]
                  if($img) { ?>
                      <li><img src="<?php echo $img; ?>"></li>
              <?php } 
           }
         ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```